# Special characters in CSV (utf-8) file appear as ? on new laptop but not on old one (both with Excel 2016)

Tags: csv, utf-8, special-characters, excel-2016

I regularly export CSV files from Shopware and edit them in Excel (Windows 10 + Office 2016). The special symbols appear garbled (e.g. â€“) but I can correct that with a "find-and-replace" macro. Annoying but workable.

However, I just got a new laptop also with Windows 10 + Office 2016 but there, the special symbols appear as white question marks on black diamonds (��). When I open the same files on the old PC I still get the good old garbled (but fixable) special symbols.

I have checked every setting I can think of but cannot find any difference between the 2 PCs. Does anyone have an idea what could be causing this and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Just in case you haven't already done this, three easy things to verify are that [1] Both machines have exactly the same O/S and patch level [2] The same locale. [3] The same default encoding. You can get the first two by clicking the Start button and typing _System Information_. To get the default encoding open a PowerShell window and submit **[System.Text.Encoding]::Default**. It might also to be helpful to update your question with that information.

Comment: Thanks for this helpful advice. It turns out they have the same O/S, patch level and locale but different default encoding. I don't know offhand how to change the encoding on the new computer but I presume that's easy enough to find out.

Comment: [1] OK. I don't know how to change the default encoding on Windows 10, and I'm not sure that it is even possible, but you should probably pursue that issue on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) rather than here if necessary. [2] With respect to your specific problem, perhaps the answer for this issue [.csv import creating black diamond with a question mark](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Software-questions/csv-import-creating-black-diamond-with-a-question-mark/qaq-p/1297674) might help? There should be a solution for your problem regardless of your PC's default encoding.

Comment: Thank you so much! I figured out how to change the encoding. It was under Control panel / Clock and Region /  Administrative / Change System locale => there I found a little box which I unclicked => Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support.  Now I get "garbled" special characters again instead of question marks. And that problem can now be solved with Mark Tolonen's tip below re. Text Editor + saving with UTF-8 w/ BOM.

Comment: OK. Good that you solved it. For several reasons it would be helpful for the community if you created an answer for your own question rather than having your solution buried in the comments.

Comment: You don't need to change the system locale, esp. to a beta feature (meaning probably buggy). I have Windows 10 and Excel 2016 and writing the CSV file as UTF-8 w/ BOM or UTF-16 /w BOM reads fine.  There is another problem.  If you like, post a link to the actual data file that appears garbled and I'll take a look.  It would also be interesting to know what the system locale was on the old and new system.

Answer (score 1):

The "garbled characters" in the old laptop are UTF-8-encoded file data decoded as (probably) Windows-1252 encoding.  It seems like the new laptop is using a different default encoding.

If you export your CSV files as UTF-8 w/ BOM and Excel will display them properly without "find-and-replace".  If Shopware doesn't have the option to export as UTF-8 w/ BOM, you can use an editor like [NotePad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to load the UTF-8-encoded CSV and re-save it as UTF-8 w/ BOM.

The UTF-16 encoding should also work if that is an option for export.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. You were right - the old laptop uses Windows-1252 encoding. I have tried UTF-8 as well as exporting the data as XML. Both solve the special characters problem but unfortunately create new ones. 
When I import the CSV data into excel, it does not always appear in the correct column, e.g. if there are 6 columns of data, the data that belongs in column F appears in column A, line 2.
XML does not mess up the columns or special characters, but excel does not always let me import the data due to reference schemas not being found.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks! After sorting out the default encoding issue on my new laptop (thanks to @skomisa + a little googling), my data appears in orderly columns with "garbled" characters instead of the dreaded ???. With that problem solved, I can now use your UTF-8 w/ BOM solution to keep my special characters.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit was an optional beta setting under Control panel / Clock and Region / Administrative / Change System locale => Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support. Once I unchecked the box, the �� disappeared and everything was back to normal.

[image: Region Settings]

The next part of the solution is to open the CSV files with a text editor, e.g. Notepad, and save them with UTF-8 w/ BOM encoding. After doing that, the special characters appear correctly in Excel, eliminating the need for "find and replace".

[image: UTF-8 with BOM]

Big thanks to Mark Tolonen + Skomisa for pointing me in the right direction.